# Java - Definition of classes interfering with each other

Tags: java, class, user-interface

I'm creating a GUI app in Java, and I am working on adding multiple themes, so I decided to make a Theme class. This is how it looks like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class Theme
{
    private static Color someColor;

    public Theme (Color color) {
        someColor = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return someColor;
    }
}
```

In my main class, I created two instances of this Theme class like this:

```
Theme theme1 = new Theme(Color.RED);
Theme theme2 = new Theme(Color.BLUE);
```

What this should do is create a theme where the color is red, and another where the color is blue. However, if I call theme1.getColor() below these two lines, I get the blue color for some reason. Somehow, my definition of theme2 is interfering with the variables inside theme1. How should I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't make `someColor` static.

Comment: The `static` in `private static Color someColor` means it is shared by all instances.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Typing the entire word "static" correctly isn't a typo; it's a bug (here).  But I'm sure there's lots of dupes for closing it.